# ListView showing less items after updating adapter - android

Tags: android, json, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I am pulling some data from JSON to my ListView using my custom adapter:

```
adapter = new ActorAdapter(this, R.layout.data_item, actorsList);
```

The JSON contains 5 items. Everything is fine, all items are showing, but... as I am using also Location services, I need to update the ListView (distance etc.).

This is happening here:

```
       private void updateUI(Location loc) {
        double Act1=loc.getLatitude();
        double Act2=loc.getLongitude();

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.clear();adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        new GetContacts().execute();}
```

The problem was, that after each update, my ListView had the same data more times - duplicates. So as you can see above, I've tried to use `adapter.clear();adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

However, this is working almost fine, no more duplicates - but after each update the ListView is always showing only 4 items instead of 5.

So first time the ListView loads 5 items - OK, but after next and each update it shows only 4 items. That's strange and can't find the issue why is that...

Attaching my GetContacts Async task:

```
    class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Okoli.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading data");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... args) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();
        String url = "androidnews.json";
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);Double myDistx;

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                JSONArray actors = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                for (int i = 0; i < actors.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = actors.getJSONObject(i);

                    Actors actor = new Actors();

                    double g1 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps1"));
                    double g2 = Double.parseDouble(c.getString("gps2"));
                    double Act1=loc.getLatitude();
                    double Act2=loc.getLongitude();

                    myDistx = meterDistanceBetweenPoints(g1,g2,Act1,Act2);

                    actor.setNazov(c.getString("name"));
                    actor.setPerex(c.getString("perex"));
                    actor.setPlace(c.getString("place"));
                    actor.setGps1(c.getString("gps1"));
                    actor.setGps2(c.getString("gps2"));

                    actor.setDist(myDistx);

                    actorsList.add(actor);

                }

            }  catch (final JSONException e) {
              Okoli.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(Okoli.this.getApplicationContext(),
                                "Data error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }); }

            return true;

        } else {
             Okoli.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(Okoli.this.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Network error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

and also my adapter:

```
public class ActorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Actors> {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Actors> actorList;
private LayoutInflater vi;
private int Resource;

ActorAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Actors> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context = context;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    actorList = objects; }

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.tvNazov = v.findViewById(R.id.tvNazov);
        holder.tvPlace = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPlace);
        holder.tvPerex = v.findViewById(R.id.tvPerex);
        holder.tvDist = v.findViewById(R.id.tvDist);
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }

holder.tvNazov.setText(actorList.get(position).getNazov());
    holder.tvPlace.setText(actorList.get(position).getPlace());
    holder.tvPerex.setText(actorList.get(position).getPerex());

    String newDist = String.format("%.1f", actorList.get(position).getDist());
    holder.tvDist.setText(newDist);

    return v;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView tvNazov;
    TextView tvPerex;
    TextView tvPlace;
    TextView tvDist;
    }
}
```

Comment: We'd need to see the getcontacts async task and your actoradapter as well

Comment: Added to my question

Comment: i don't see how you update the data inside the adapter. Usually you add a setData/addData method to your adapter. Then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter refers to `actorsList` as data source but this variable is never emptied.

Comment: hm, but how to empty tha actorsList then? I tried to use `actorsList.clear();` but didn't help. I tried to Log the count of items in GetContacts immediately after JSON, and first time it is 5, next and each time is 4 - `Log.e("count",String.format("value = %d", actors.length()));`

Comment: ok, so I investigated, it might by something with my JSON. It has this structure: `{"result": [{"letter": "","name": "Myname",...` and when I log the jsonStr response from url, first time there is that empty letter, but next time it is ignored and the first item in JSON is name. For some reason it ignores the Letter in JSON when it is empty. When I fill the Letter in my JSON for each item, then the count is working fine.

Comment: I assume you found the reason then. You can empty your `actorsList` as you did with `actorsList.clear()` but you have to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the adapter again after filling it in your AsyncTask (`onPostExecute()`)

Comment: hm, seems I was wrong - when I fill the Letter with some data, it works on other lists, but not here where I need to update the ListView more times. In onPostExecute() I already have the notifyDatasetChanged(). The problem is , that on each update it is ignoring the first item in JSON - Letter, doesn't matter if it is empty or not. First time it is ok - it shows also the letter, but on each update the Log show only `{"result": [{"name": "myName"...` and the letter is missing. And my app shows an error - No value for letter.

Comment: Well, now I reinstalled my app on my device, rerun the debugging, leaving `adapter.clear();adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and now it seems working fine, the letter is always there .. maybe json was cached or not sure what was the issue, but now after each update, the letter is showing too. Maybe I should somehow avoid json caching